# SQL Query END AS value not working correctly

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a table on my website that displays the top 10 students with the lowest 'value'. There is no actual 'value' column in my database, instead there are two columns intitled 'grade1' and 'grade2'. My goal is for the query to display the lowest 10 results as the 'value' whether its in grade1 or grade2 column.

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.class, e.teacher, k.notes, s.grade1, s.grade2
            , s.gradedmethod, k.studentid
            , CASE WHEN s.gradedmethod= 'A' OR s. gradedmethod= 'B' THEN s.grade1
                   ELSE s.grade2 END AS value
FROM Table1 k 
INNER JOIN Table2 p ON p.class = k.class 
INNER JOIN Table3 d ON d.tier = p.tier 
INNER JOIN Table4 e ON e.teacher = p.teacher 
INNER JOIN Table5 s ON k.studentid = s.studentid 
WHERE s.examdate IN 
      (SELECT MAX(st.examdate) 
       FROM Table5 st 
       WHERE st.studentid = s.studentid 
       GROUP BY st.studentid) 
   AND k.reportcard IS NULL AND (k.cardtype = 'X' OR k.cardtype = 'Y') 
ORDER BY value ASC
```

Here is a sample of the output (EDIT: results compressed to include only GRADE1/GRADE2/VALUE):

```
    Class/Teacher/Notes/Grade1/Grade2/MeasureMethod/Studentid/Value
   NULL/35/NULL
   NULL/82/NULL
   NULL/88/NULL
   NULL/87/NULL
   0/100//0
   19/21/19
   24/13/24
   27/40/27
   NULL/28/28
   33/23/33
```

As you can see, something is going wrong as the first four results in the value column are displaying as NULL when they should have been Grade2, however on the 9th row it functioned properly...

Finally, another problem is that I only want the query to include results if the student has been graded 3 times or more. *note: grade1 and grade2 are actually two sections on the same exam. Every students graded exam is a row in table5 that includes a column grade1 and grade2. So if there are 3 rows or more with the same studentid then he or she should be included.

I am a beginner programmer and I am blocking at this point as I have no idea how to make this happen and my research is only further confusing me at this point. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think they should have been grade2? ... What I mean is, is the gradedmethod for those rows not 'A' or 'B'?

Comment: Your results are difficult to read. Can you possibly compress them to show just `grade1`, `grade2`, and `value`?

Comment: @KyleHale No they are indeed A or B, that aspect is working fine (however once I integrated your INNER JOIN strategy I had to insert the CASE WHEN a second time in the parenthesis for it to work). Not sure if I understood your question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case statement says if the gradedmethod of the student is "A" or "B" return grade1 ... even if it's null.
So either you need to:

- modify the student's gradedmethods to not be "A" or "B", or
- Change your case statement to add "AND grade 1 is not null" to the first WHEN condition to fall back to grade2 if grade1 is null

Not sure what the requirement is (don't show non-NULL grades? what's the gradedmethod do exactly?) so I can't tell you for sure how to avoid what you're seeing.

To get students with 3 grades, add this JOIN to your query:

```
INNER JOIN (select studentid from Table5 group by studentid having count(studentid) > 3) threeGrades on threeGrades.studentid = s.studentid
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, was very helpful. The only problem I'm still having is that it doesn't put GRADE2 as VALUE until it hits a row where GRADE1 is present, from there on if GRADE1 is NULL it assigns GRADE2 as VALUE. Strange...

Comment: I .. don't think that's what it's doing. The CASE statement says "Is this student's gradedmethod "A" or "B"? If so, put in Grade1. If not, put in Grade2." For that 9th row, what is that student's gradedmethod?